# auto formatting one lined statement to multi-line in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

Here is a simple example of a one-lined IF statement.

```
if(condition)
    something = "blah";
```

I find myself using them often for simple things, but later on while expanding the application, expanding them to a multi-lined if statements

```
if(condition)
{
    something = "blah;
    somethingElse = "blar";
}
```

But I find this quite frustrating because I have to go through several steps to do so. When I enter the first brace, my code formatter (Visual Studio? Resharper?) proceeds to enter a second (closing) brace, and formats it like so:

```
if(condition) { }
something = "blah";
```

I then have to select and remove the closing brace, and do my own formatting to get it to look correct.

Is there a way that I can conveniently have resharper or visual studio automatically enter the braces around the one-lined IF statement? e.g: I entered an opening brace after the condition and it automatically formatted it like

```
if(condition)
{
    something = "blah";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3622563/1583

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReSharper - force curly braces around single line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622236/resharper-force-curly-braces-around-single-line)

Comment: Not a duplicate, i dont want to force curly braces around single lined statements. I want to make it easier to switch between the two.

Comment: It is not clear that you want to go back from `{}` to none as well.

Comment: I did not see that as being feasible, therefore I didn't include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is define a new snippet that is exactly like the if code snippet without the "if ($expression)" part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>multiif</Title>
            <Shortcut>multiif</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet for multiline if statement</Description>
            <Author>Microsoft Corporation</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>expression</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Expression to evaluate</ToolTip>
                    <Default>true</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[
    {
        $selected$ $end$
    }]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Then you can import this snippet into visual studio by:

1. Select Code Snippet Manager... from the Tools menu.
2. Click on the Import... button.
3. Navigate to your new snippet file.

or:
Copy your new snippet file into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#

You can then select the body of your single line if statement in your c# file, right click and select Surround With... then select your new snippet.

Comment: It is not quite what i was thinking of, but it works. thanks.