# How can I force Resharper to place the curly brace on the same line?

Tags: c#, resharper

if I type in:

```
if (id < 0) {
```

followed by Enter key, Resharper re-formats it into.

```
if (id < 0) 
{

}
```

How can I tell it to reformat it into below, e.g. keep the brace with the `if` statement?

```
if (id < 0) {

}
```

P.S.  I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622236/resharper-force-curly-braces-around-single-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) question, but it addresses forcing curly braces around a single line, not keeping the brace with the `if` statement.

Comment: Serious?, Please don't !!! ...

Comment: @TimonPost Give it a shot for a day or a small project.  Once I tried, I couldn't go back.  The code looks and smells so much better.

Comment: @AngryHacker this isnt Javascript, its C#.  Dont fight the IDE

Comment: @maccettura The VS IDE actually [supports](https://i.imgur.com/0PxEJmJ.png) that style.  It's Resharper that was fighting me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the other question you linked, it's really close to this, but it might be the difference you are interested in.  I don't know if you can set K&R for just 'if' statements (as opposed to everything under 'Other'), but you can definitely set K&R as the standard across the board.

Indentation style can be found in the Options window under:

**Code Editing > [Language] > Formatting Style > Braces Layout**

[image]

This is as of Resharper 2018.1.2

Answer (score 1):

From the `ReSharper` menu, choose `Options`, then navigate to: 
**`Code Editing --> C# --> Formatting Style --> Braces Layout`**.

From there you can choose either:

> - At end of line (K&R style)
> - At end of line (no space)

---

[image]